# Why are elements in HashSet in random order?

Tags: java

I am wondering how does the place of the element in a HashSet is determined. Is it through some built-in hash function?

```
Set <String>set=new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("January");
    set.add("February");
    set.add("July");
    set.add("August");
    set.add("September");
    set.add("October");
    set.add("Novermber");
    set.add("December");
    set.add("March");
    set.add("April");
    set.add("May");
    set.add("June");


    Iterator <String>it=set.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

I get this result

```
June
October
December
September
May
March
Novermber
July
January
February
April
August
```

What is the explanation for this order or the output?

Comment: There's a difference between not guaranteeing they are in the order of insertion and saying they're arranged randomly. [As the docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): "*It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set*".

Comment: BTW, regarding your question on re-hashing: it wasn't a duplicate and it's a perfectly legitimate question to ask. But there are many hash-based maps and they behave very differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HashSet is based on array. Item index in array is calculated based on `hashCode()` function.

Iterator in HashSet moves over array elements, skipping null elements. That's why your order is 'strange'. If you need to preserve insertion order, use `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pay for ordering (in most cases in form of computational time). And the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) states explicitly, that "*[...]. It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*"

Therefore I think the order is disregarded for the sake of performance.