# Java HashMap Key Confusing

Tags: java

```
private static final HashMap<StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode, Product> FIRST_FOUR_SYMBOLS_HASH_CODE_PRODUCT_HASH_MAP = new HashMap<StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode, Product>() {{
        put(new StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode("121"), new Product("prod1", "100500"));
        put(new StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode("45631232"), new Product("prod2", "400500"));
        put(new StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode("6442112"), new Product("prod3", "20500"));
        put(new StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode("4562121"), new Product("prod4", "22500"));
        put(new StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode("4321"), new Product("prod5", "1020"));
    }};
```

**StringFirstFourSymbolHashCode** overrided methods

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 0;
    for(Character character : string.toCharArray()){
        hashCode += character;
    }
    return hashCode;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode)) {
        return false;
    }
    StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode stringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode = (StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode)obj;
    return string.equals(stringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode.string);
}
```

When I out elements from HashMap they outs very strange. How I can see HashMap's keys ordered by increase, but why after 410 outs 202

```
> StringHashCodeLength HasMap Iterator
> StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode{string='121,
> hashCode=148}=Product:name='prod1, cost='100500}
> StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode{string='6442112,
> hashCode=356}=Product:name='prod3, cost='20500}
> StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode{string='4562121,
> hashCode=357}=Product:name='prod4, cost='22500}
> StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode{string='45631232,
> hashCode=410}=Product:name='prod2, cost='400500}
> StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode{string='4321,
> hashCode=202}=Product:name='prod5, cost='1020}
```

Please, explain how it works

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't define any ordering at all. If you need entries be returned in the order they're inserted, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead. If you need entries be returned ordered by key value, use any of [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671239/why-are-elements-in-hashset-in-random-order

Comment: You may wait entries be ordered by hash code, but this does not happen: 1) when hash table is small, entries of multiple hashcodes may be placed in the same bucket; 2) to decide which particular cell an entry should occupy in the hashtable, additional calculation on hashcode is performed (e. g. `cell = hash % 8` if table size is 8)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
 private static final SortedMap<StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode, Product> FIRST_FOUR_SYMBOLS_HASH_CODE_PRODUCT_HASH_MAP =
 new  SortedMap<StringFirstFourSymbolsHashCode, Product>()
```

you just change HashMap with SortedMap.